# Google v8 Engine licenses

Tags: v8

Is it possible to use v8 in a commercial project?

and if so, what Google is requesting to done with that?

To be more clear, i am creating something that requires a scripting engine, so i selected v8

regards..

Comment: It's best to consult a lawyer with these questions.